# DJI Mavic Mini 2 can't record 2.7k 60fps after update

Tags: troubleshooting, video, dji-mavic-mini, dji-mini-2

As announced, DJI Mavic Mini 2 should support 2.7k 60fps.

I have the latest update of 01.02.0300 but still do not see the option.

Does anybody have the same problem ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit of research it seems like the problem is likely to be that you don't have the latest version of the DJI fly app. As per [this forum thread](https://mavicpilots.com/threads/2-7k-48-50-60fps-does-not-appear-after-01-02-00100-firmware-update.105996/) you will need version 1.2.4 or later to see the option for 2.7k 60fps.

On android you will need to download the latest APK, while on iOS it can be downloaded from the App Store. Links to both version are availible on [the dji website](https://www.dji.com/se/dji-fly#download).

Comment: Ah, I see last update 13.11.2020 which can actually cause the problem. Unfortunatelly, my phone has only Android 9 and most probably DJI Fly app requires atleast 10 or 11 to update... don't know, but thank you for explaining!